# Implement discounts in magento 1.9 with magento wallet functionality

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am have implemented custom discounts in magento which is working properly.But, when discount is implemented and someone is trying to pay from magento wallet balance, wallet seems to stop working and the amount paid from wallet does not get deducted from the grand total of the cart.

Discount is applied as follows:
config.xml-

```
<sales>
      <quote>
            <totals>
                <discount>
                    <class>Uf_Rewards_Model_Discount</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount>
            </totals>
        </quote> 
  </sales>
```

Discount.php:

```
class Uf_Rewards_Model_Discount extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount {


    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {

        if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'billing')
            return $this;

        $discount = 10; //your discount percent
        $grandTotal = $address->getGrandTotal();
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();
        $totals = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
        $address->setFeeAmount(-$discount);
        $address->setBaseFeeAmount(-$discount);
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $address->getFeeAmount());
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        $address->setDiscountAmount(-$discount);
        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-$discount);
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'billing')
            return $this;

        $amt = $address->getFeeAmount();
        //  $amt=300;

        if ($amt != 0) {
            Mage::log($amt, NULL, 'obsrvr.log');
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code' => 'Discount',
                'title' => 'Discount',
                'value' => $amt
            ));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try tor write all step how you create custom discount. May I know how you create wallet functionality

Comment: Wallet is the existing functionality in magento 1.9

Comment: have you install extension?

Comment: yes i have installed extension

Comment: which extension have you used for wallet?

Comment: Sorry its not an extension

Comment: so have you develop custom extension magento wallet because magento did not get default wallet system.

Comment: I already have the wallet functionality developed

Comment: May I know that code